# For all reports, CiviReport shows a page with no content

Tags: civireport, reports

I'm getting a mostly blank screen when trying to run reports. I see the CiviCRM menu and page heading, then the page footer, with nothing in between.

[image]

I get the same thing for every report and every report template. The "Manage Templates" screen works, but if I click "Edit" on a template, I get a pop-up with no content.

I have no errors in the CiviCRM log file, no errors in my PHP log file, and no browser console errors. This is CiviCRM 4.6.26.

What steps can I take to further troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Do you have the extended reports extension installed? I had something similar awhile back and extended reports needed an upgrade.

Comment: Nope, I don't have Extended Reports installed.

Comment: Can you right click, and use Inspect and Console to dig out some errors your browser might be detecting

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thanks, but I already tried that -- there are no browser console errors

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this issue whilst upgrading from ver 5.3 to 5.4 (using Drupal 7 as the CMS).  After a couple of frustrating days going through the debugger and finding nothing, I did a fresh 5.40 install on a VM and all was fine.

Going back over the steps I took upgrading, and retraced - one of the steps was to clear down the files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US directory.  I cleared down everything I could in the en_US directory and all was fine.

See [Clear Cached file](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/) in the section

> Upgrade in Drupal 7